# "Infinite loop" causing unreachable code

Tags: loops, go, tokenize

i'm currently trying to work with the html tokenizer https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html.

So what i want to do is following: get all links from url and if url contains a certain string -> add to url-list.

```
resp, err = client.Get("someurl")
var urls []string

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

z := html.NewTokenizer(resp.Body)

for {
    tt := z.Next()

    switch {
    case tt == html.ErrorToken:
        return
    case tt == html.StartTagToken:
        t := z.Token()

        isAnchor := t.Data == "a"
        if !isAnchor {
            continue
        }

        ok, url := getHref(t)
        if !ok {
            continue
        }
        if strings.Contains(url, "somestring") {
            urls = append(urls, url)
        }

    }
}

fmt.Println(urls)
```

This doesn't work since "fmt.Println(urls)" is unreachable. The loop ofc ends at some point.... but this doesn't compile. How do i get the code after the loop to be reachable?

Regards

Comment: Also look here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/85

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `break` in the loop. The only way it ends is via a `return` which sends control out of this function. This means that `fmt.Println(urls)` is not reachable.

Try this:

```
L:
for {
    tt := z.Next()

    switch {
    case tt == html.ErrorToken:
        break L
    case tt == html.StartTagToken:
        t := z.Token()

        isAnchor := t.Data == "a"
        if !isAnchor {
            continue
        }

        ok, url := getHref(t)
        if !ok {
            continue
        }
        if strings.Contains(url, "somestring") {
            urls = append(urls, url)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that go to statement? but that is a bad design

Answer (score 1):

Use the example they provided here: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html#example-Parse

Modifying your code to fit this:

```
resp, err = client.Get("someurl")
var urls []string

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

doc, err := html.Parse(strings.NewReader(resp.Body))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

var f func(*html.Node)
f = func(n *html.Node) {
    if n.Type == html.ElementNode && n.Data == "a" {
        for _, a := range n.Attr {
            if a.Key == "href" {
                fmt.Println(a.Val)

                if strings.Contains(a.Val, "somestring") {
                    urls = append(urls, a.Val)
                }

                break
            }
        }
    }
    for c := n.FirstChild; c != nil; c = c.NextSibling {
        f(c)
    }
}
f(doc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pud the loop in a function and exit with retrun form it.